# push e.which to array is not equal to given array

Tags: jquery, keydown, keyevent, keyup

Any ideas what here's wrong? Can't figure it out... It says that `arr` is not equal to `[17, 67]`

```
var key = function(keys, fn) {
    var arr = [];
    $(document).on({
        keydown: function(e) {
            arr.push(e.which);
            if (arr === keys) {
                fn();
            }
        },
        keyup: function() {
            arr = [];
        }
    });
};

// ctrl + c
key([17, 67], function() {
    alert(true);
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Aw3Dj/)

**Update**

Since [Cymen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13672752/1250044)'s answer it works, however if you press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> and then <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> or vice versa you have to fire the second shortcut twice to work, any ideas?

New [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Aw3Dj/2/).

```
var key = function(keys, fn) {
    var arr = [];
    $(document).on({
        keydown: function(e) {
            arr.push(e.which);
            for (var i = 0; keys[i]; i++) {
                if (arr[i] !== keys[i]) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            fn(e);
            arr = [];
        },
        keyup: function() {
            arr = [];
        }
    });
};

// ctrl + c
key([17, 67], function() {
    alert(true);
});

// ctrl + alt + c
key([17, 18, 67], function() {
    alert('ctrl+alt+c');
});
```

Comment: Is this a new attempt at breaking the [Konami code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konami_Code) ?

Comment: No, not really.. i just need a simple shortcut/key event handler...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `===` to check if arrays are equal by content. Check it out with a JavaScript console:

```
[17, 35] === [17, 35]
false

a = [17, 35]
[17, 35]
a === a
true
```

So `===` on arrays is checking the reference not the value. You can use something else like underscore do the comparison or write one yourself if it is some sort of challenge. Or since you're only comparing two elements, do this:

```
var key = function(keys, fn) {
    var arr = [];
    $(document).on({
        keydown: function(e) {
            arr.push(e.which);
            if (arr[0] === keys[0] && arr[1] === keys[1]) {
                fn();
                arr = [];  // added this to avoid buggyness
            }
            console.log(arr);
            console.log(keys);
        },
        keyup: function() {
            arr = [];
        }
    });
};

// ctrl + c
key([17, 67], function() {
    alert(true);
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9LbsD/

### For more than two keys like CTRL+ALT+C

```
You need an array comparison that works for variable lengths like this one:

var equalArrays = function(array1, array2) {
    if (array1.length != array2.length) {
        return false;
    }
    for (var i=0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        if (array1[i] !== array2[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;    
}

var key = function(keys, fn) {
    var arr = [];
    $(document).on({
        keydown: function(e) {
            arr.push(e.which);
            console.log('arr', arr, 'keys', keys, 'match', equalArrays(arr, keys));
            if (equalArrays(arr, keys)) {
                fn();
                arr = [];                
            }
            console.log(arr);
            console.log(keys);
        },
        keyup: function() {
            arr = [];
        }
    });
};

// ctrl + c
key([17, 67], function() {
    alert(true);
});

// ctrl + alt + c
key([17, 18, 67], function() {
    alert('ctrl+alt+c');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WZLut/

### A less buggy approach

We need to keep track of which keys were pressed however a single key can only be pressed once in one combination (I'm assuming) and on keyup we should only remove the key going up not all the keys. So here is a working approach to that:

```
var equalArrays = function(array1, array2) {
    return _.isEqual(array1, array2);
}

var key = function(keys, fn) {
    var arr = [];
    $(document).on({
        keydown: function(e) {
            arr = _.without(arr, e.which);
            arr.push(e.which);
            if (equalArrays(arr, keys)) {
                fn();             
            }
        },
        keyup: function(e) {
            arr = _.without(arr, e.which);
            arr = _.uniq(arr);
        }
    });
};

// ctrl + c
key([17, 67], function() {
    alert('ctrl+c');
});

// ctrl + alt + c
key([17, 18, 67], function() {
    alert('ctrl+alt+c');
});
```

​

http://jsfiddle.net/BgQUA/

Comment: No problem. Added one small bug fix that I need under chrome (see comment next to it -- added this to avoid buggyness).

Comment: Yeah, have seen this, very helpful.

Comment: Hmm, your approach is not bad, but this part `if (arr[0] === keys[0] && arr[1] === keys[1])` kills shortcuts like `ctrl + alt + c`. Any ideas?

Comment: You need an array comparison that works with variable array length: http://jsfiddle.net/WZLut/

Comment: ...and even in vanilla-script: http://fiddle.jshell.net/WZLut/3/ :-) thanks for your help! :-*

Comment: Okay, my (and your) results are still not perfect! If you press `ctrl + a` and then `ctrl + alt + a` you have to fire the second shortcut twice to work... any ideas?

Comment: I think we have to be more intelligent about removing keys and being sure we don't have duplicate keys in the array of pressed keys. This seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/BgQUA/

Comment: A way to do it without underscore is not in sight or? ♥

Comment: All you have to do is rewrite the underscore methods in plain JavaScript. But honestly, why bother? Underscore is good and doesn't rely on jQuery. If you just want the functions, grab them from the Underscore source or reference it for the rewrite.